# flutter: custom color for App Bar with ThemeData

Tags: flutter

How can I make a custom color for App Bar with ThemeData?
`accentColor` is deprecated while `colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo))` expects type `MaterialColor`.

I know that I can make it this way

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        title: Text('CAPTION'),
      ),
```

But I want to specify it in `ThemeData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rather than overriding everything, it often makes sense to extend the parent theme. You can handle this by using the copyWith() method.

More about [extending-the-parent-theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme).

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: const T1(),
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    appBarTheme: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.copyWith(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the first way is to set it with `backroundColor` property.

If this property is `null`, then the `AppBarTheme.backgroundColor` is used. `AppBarTheme` can be set using `appBarTheme` property of `ThemeData`.

If `AppBarTheme.backgroundColor` is also null, then `AppBar` uses the overall theme's `ColorScheme.primary` if the overall theme's brightness is `Brightness.light`, and `ColorScheme.surface` if the overall theme's `brightness` is `Brightness.dark`.